# How to concatenate multiple rows into a single row in ASP.NET MVC EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 tables:

- Recipe
- RecipeIngredient (fk RecipeId)
- RecipeTag (fk RecipeId)

**Recipe**

```
+-----+------------+-------------+------+
| Id  |    Name    | Ingredients | Tags |
+-----+------------+-------------+------+
|  99 | Mango Sago |             |      |
| 100 | Tuna Melt  |             |      |
+-----+------------+-------------+------+
```

**RecipeIngredient**

```
+-----+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id  | Quantity |    UOM     |                    Name                     | RecipeId |
+-----+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
| 115 | 2        | Pieces     | Whole Ripe Mangoes                          |       99 |
| 116 | 1        | Pieces     | Jolly Coconut Milk, 400ml                   |       99 |
| 117 | 2        | Tablespoon | Sugar                                       |       99 |
| 118 | 1        | Cup        | Cooked Tapioca Pearls                       |       99 |
| 119 | NULL     | NULL       | Mango Cubes                                 |       99 |
| 120 | 1        | Pieces     | Doña Elena 100% Tuna Shredded 185g, drained |      100 |
| 121 | 2        | Tablespoon | White Onion, chopped                        |      100 |
| 122 | 2        | Tablespoon | Jolly Real Mayonnaise                       |      100 |
| 123 | 1        | Tablespoon | Celery or Pickle Relish, finely chopped     |      100 |
| 124 | 8        | Pieces     | White Bread                                 |      100 |
| 125 | 4        | Pieces     | Cheddar or Mozzarella Cheese                |      100 |
+-----+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
```

**RecipeTag**

```
+----+-----------------+----------+
| Id |      Name       | RecipeId |
+----+-----------------+----------+
| 72 | Filipino Desert |       99 |
| 73 | Quick Recipe    |       99 |
| 74 | Quick Recipe    |      100 |
+----+-----------------+----------+
```

How do I add all the `RecipeIngredient` to the `Ingredients` column in the `Recipe` table and add all the `RecipeTag` to the `Tags` column in the `Recipe` table in the controller?

[image: Output I want]

```
public JsonResult GetAllRecipes()
{
    var recipes = db.Recipes.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
    return new JsonResult { Data = recipes, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: If you want to do this using EF and linq, then you will need to get your data  and then use the [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) methods of `String` (or an `.Aggregate()` clause)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: You now seem to be asking how to add the concatenated values to the `Ingredients` and `Tags` fields of the `Recipe` table. Why would you want to do that? - you not normalizing data - that data already exists in the `RecipeIngredient` and `RecipeTag` tables.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm going to display the Recipe Table using Angular-datatable and I need it to all appear just like the select John Woo did so the user can search using ingredients and tags and the recipe will appear.

Comment: Therefore you should be formatting the data in the GET method that displays that view (not saving the same data in multiple places)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah I was trying to do that too but It's not displaying right so I thought maybe I should just add it to to a new column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163455/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-klentdiamond).

Comment: Solutions do **not** go in the question (that s what the answers are for). I have rolled back your changes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public JsonResult GetAllRecipes()
{
    var recipes = (from rec db.Recipes
                   join ing in db.Ingredients on rec.Id equals ing.RecipeId into subIngrs
                   from subIngr in subIngrs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   join tag in db.RecipeTags on rec.Id equals tag.RecipeId into subTags
                   from subTag in subTags.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   order by rec.Name
                   select new 
                   {
                       rec.Id,
                       rec.Name,
                       Quantity = subIngr == null ? null : subIngr.Quantity, 
                       IngrName = subIngr == null ? null : subIngr.Name, 
                       UOM = subIngr == null ? null : subIngr.UOM, 
                       TagName = subTag == null ? null : subTag.Name 
                   }).ToList()
                   .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name }).Select(x => new 
                   {
                       x.Key.Id,
                       x.Key.Name,
                       Ingredients = string.Join("," x.Where(y => y.IngrName != null).Select(y => $"{y.Quantity} {y.UOM} {y.Name}").Distinct()),
                       Tags = string.Join("," x.Where(y => y.TagName != null).Select(y => y.TagName).Distinct())
                   }).ToList();

    return new JsonResult { Data = recipes, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: @KlentDiamond, yes, it is my fault, try it with `y` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `STUFF` if you want to do it in sql.

```
SELECT  a.Id,
        Recipe = a.Name,
        Ingredient = STUFF((
              SELECT ',' 
                     + CAST(b.Quantity AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' ' 
                     + b.UOM + ' ' 
                     + b.Name
              FROM dbo.RecipeIngredient b
              WHERE a.Id = b.RecipeId
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
         Tag = STUFF((
              SELECT ',' + c.Name
              FROM dbo.RecipeTag c
              WHERE a.ID = c.RecipeId
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    Recipe a
```

Here's a [Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfc9f/6)

To execute the stored procedure and return the results as a json in your controller method

```
var recipies = db.Database.SqlQuery<RecipeVM>("NameOfStoredProcedure");
return Json(recipes, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

where `RecipeVM` is

```
public class RecipeVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ingredient { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but you missed the `Quantity` and `UOM` fields from the `RecipeIngredient` (i.e. `2 Pieces Whole Ripe Mangoes`, rather than `Whole Ripe Mangoes`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh yes, just need to concatenate it with `Quantity`. I just updated the answer.

Comment: @JohnWoo This is great! But I how do I do this in MVC controller?

Comment: @KlentDiamond basically the query above is only a `SELECT` statement and does nothing with the table. What I can suggest is if you want to add the values in `Recipe` table, you have to create a Stored Procedure and modify the select into update statement and call it after the user have added all tags and ingredients. [Example demo to make it an update statement](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b818/4)

Comment: @JohnWoo This would work too If I could just figure out how to do this in mvc controller. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KlentDiamond, In case John is not familiar with mvc, I'll edit this into his answer shortly

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set up your navigation properties correctly (i.e. `Recipe` contains `public virtual ICollection<RecipieIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }` etc) then to get the data in the concatenated format you want,

```
public JsonResult GetAllRecipes()
{
    var recipes = db.Recipes
        .OrderBy(r => r.Name)
        .ToList() // this is necessary because we need Linq to Objects for the string formatting
        .Select(r => new // can be anonymous objects because we are returning a JsonResult
        {
            Id = r.Id,
            Name = r.Name,
            Ingredients = r.Ingredients
                .Select(i => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", i.Quantity, i.UOM, i.Name).TrimStart())
                .Aggregate((c, n) => c + ", " + n),
            Tags = r.Tags
                .Select(t => t.Name)
                .Aggregate((c, n) => c + ", " + n)
        });
    return Json(recipes, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Side note, your `RecipeIngredient` table indicates nullable values for `Quantity` and `UOM` hence the `TrimStart`. I am assuming that if either `Quantity` or `UOM` is `null`, then the other is also `null`

Alternatively, (in LINQ to SQL) you can use

```
var recipes = (from r in db.Recipies
               join i in db.RecipeIngredient on r.Id equals i.RecipeId into Ingedients
               join t in db.RecipeTag on r.Id equals t.RecipeId into Tags
               orderby r.Name
               select new
               {
                   Name = r.Name,
                   Ingedients = Ingedients,
                   Tags = Tags
               }).ToList()
               .Select(x => new
               {
                   Name = x.Name,
                   Ingredients = x.Ingedients
                       .Select(y => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", y.Quantity, y.UOM, y.Name).Trim())
                       .Aggregate((c, n) => c + ", " + n),
                   Tags = x.Tags
                       .Select(y => y.Name)
                       .Aggregate((c, n) => c + ", " + n)
               });
return Json(recipes, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: `Quantity` and `UOM` can be null but `Ingredient Name` cannot be null. I tried your code but it returned `System.InvalidOperationException` I'll post the full exception detail in my question.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. That error suggest that perhaps one or more recipes contains no associated ingredients or tags.

Comment: I added `public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<RecipeTag> Tags { get; set; }` to my `recipe.cs` since before I only defined both as string then I replaced `Ingredients/Tags` with `RecipeIngredient/RecipeTag` but when I tried to run it, It returned `Sequence contains no elements`

Comment: OK, it sounds like you have not set up the navigation properties correctly (and you may need to use `var recipes = db.Recipes.Include(r => r.Recipies).Include(r => r.Tags).ToList().etc`). I can give you another option using Linq to SQL for the initial query but you really should be setting up your models correctly in the first place (using code first) - refer [Entity Framework Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: It will be another 30 min or so before I can get a chance to update the answer with the LINQ to SQL option.

Comment: @KlentDiamond, be aware, as this solution will perform one query for Recipes: `Select * From Recipes`, `N` queries `Select * From Ingredients Where...`  and N queries `Select * From Tags Where...`, i.e. `2*N + 1` queries(where `N` - is number of Recipes) instead of single query - **very big overhead**

Comment: Updated with LINQ to SQL option

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes now it is better. But what will be if some `Recipe` will not have `RecipeIngredient` or `RecipeTag`? And are you shure, that resulted `Ingredients` and `Tags` fields will not have duplicates? You can copy needed fixies from my answer.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov, I cannot see why you would ever have duplicate `Ingedients` or `Tags` for a `Recipe` (it would not make much sense to save duplicates), and I'm assuming that the collections will not be empty (that at least one of each is needed to save a `Recipe`), but if so then the `DefaultIfEmpty` code as per your answer would be needed

Comment: @StephenMuecke, sorry about duplicates, I not carefully looked at your answer.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov, You have nothing to be sorry about :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if you're trying to programatically insert this data from user input, you could just iterate over the ingredients/tags and build a string to insert into the relevant tables.

If you're trying to do this from existing data, then I'm not sure EF is the tool to use. I would just write SQL scripts to handle that.

Comment: I want to add it in the controller after user input. I'll update my question. Thanks.